# "docker: 'compose' is not a docker command." How to use the alias "docker compose"?

Tags: linux, docker

I'm following [this guide](https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-deploy-containers-to-azure-aci-using-docker-cli-and-compose/) in order to deploy a docker-compose application in Azure, and the command

```
docker compose up
```

is not found in Azure Container Instances (ACI).

I get the following error:

```
docker: 'compose' is not a docker command. See 'docker --help'
```

However I switched the context before with:

```
docker context use "azuremycontext"
```

Moreover, I cannot execute the command

```
docker context create aci azuremycontext
```

Docker doesn't have this option in my Linux. What am I missing here? I guess it is not linked just to ACI, but rather docker-compose itself?

Comment: Looks like a typo to me.

Comment: No, docker compose is now a golang alternative to python's docker-compose. So it should be available in new versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found the solution and would like to share it:

You have to install the docker aci integration in order to use "docker compose" and "docker create context aci [contextname]". You can install it as follows:

```
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/compose-cli/main/scripts/install/install_linux.sh | sh
```

Comment: I ran your magic script and still can't use `docker compose`.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from ['compose' is not a docker command` when installing using convenience scripts · Issue #8630](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8630#issuecomment-1141930536), this shows the most voted and also most recent answer at the time of writing (08/2022).

If your docker-compose version does not yet support "docker compose" without a dash in between, you can get the alias "docker compose" for "docker-compose" by installing a plugin.

If you see:

```bash
docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'
```

You need to:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-compose-plugin
```

Check the plugin for example with:

```bash
$ docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.6.0
```

Comment: Ah, you need to install the special tricks that nobody told you about. Ah, not available for my Linux. Typical Docker, typical Linux.

Comment: @Andrew I asked or answered a lot of plain things on Stack Exchange two years ago during a Docker project. I was new to Docker, wondering how it could be that I was the only one asking. It often turned out that nobody had asked or shared up to then, although it was needed by many.

Comment: Probably because whoever needed it before either got their hand held or read non-generic documentation, or they just gave up. A lot of these new "technologies" coming out in the software world in recent years are BS.

Comment: @Andrew Would not agree with the BS thingy, but with "got their hand held". Reminds me of that old insider teamwork where you ask only your peers and have only internal guides, if at all.